# Authenticating users on a second website with a one time querystring ID - is this secure?

Tags: tls, authentication

We need to authenticate users on a second website that are 'sent' from a first website without having to login again.

The way we plan to do this is for a single use ID to be sent to the second site in a querystring. Once received the second site contacts the first webserver via a secure web service, which says 'yes' or 'no' whether the code is genuine and they can login.

All communication will be via HTTPS.

Are there big security holes in this that we have overlooked? Is this secure?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/ Might be of some relevance

Comment: Is there a possibility of a man in the middle attack anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

It is not the best way.

If there are any third party resources or links on the target site, the query string in the URL could be revealed to them in the `referer` header.

Also, query string parameters are logged by default on the server, meaning an unscrupulous admin may be able to gain access to sessions. Same applies for any proxy servers en route that undertake application level inspections that have  a trusted SSL/TLS cert installed.

A more minor point is that it is visible on screen so a "shoulder surfer" or a camera could pick up the token.

In short, the POST method is much more secure because it does not have the above flaws.

Comment: good point on referrer header +1

Comment: You raise valid points, although the IDs are single use so that should largely mitigate those issues. Any attack would have a very small window in which to operate. I take the point on posting though - so you'd suggest simply posting the data instead of using the querystring - in that scenario you would approve of this approach? Regarding "shoulder surfing" the ID would likely be high entropy & at least 1-200 characters long so impractical to exploit and not fully visible.

Comment: Is there a possibility of a man in the middle attack anywhere?

Comment: @nii Https pretty much mitigates that.

Answer (score 0):

If the generation of unique IDs is random enough, it is secure. By random enough I mean, an attacker should not be able to figure out valid IDs belonging to other users. In example a simple md5 of incrementing numeric IDs or usernames for authentication will not be secure. If you use a mutually known secret salt in the process, it is. If you do not expose the one time ID to the user (which you shouldn't for the abovementioned reasons) and not let the user change it in any ways. Then, you can go with passing simple numeric IDs **if you validate that the request is coming from the server's IP**.

Comment: Thx. Do we even have to do anything mutually known? We are contacting their web service so as long as it's genuinely random with lots of entropy we don't need to know how it's generated - just send it back to them and get a yes / no, right?

Comment: Not neccessarily. If the user has no knowledge about how the authentication process works. You should not expose this one time ID to the user to prevent the abovementioned guessing. If your case allows this,  you should also consider going with a mutual database with a joint table mapping the two site's identities.

Comment: The first site will just generate completely random long IDs with a lot of entropy. I think this should be fine?!

Comment: Yes. It's okay.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with the user changing it or guessing is - they won't be able to guess a differet valid ID?!

Comment: Please share more details about the process of authentication. `which says 'yes' or 'no' whether the code is genuine and they can login.` what do you mean by genuine? Okay, it's absolutely random with a lot of entropy used, but how do you identify which user it belongs to?

Comment: When the code is generated - site 1 will store a reference to a user ID along with it. That information will then be sent back along with the 'yes' or 'no' using the secure web service.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally avoid passing session tokens via the URL as it provides a session hijacking opportunity. The fact yours are single use and 'verified' over a second channel somewhat mitigates this. If you take this approach, ensure that the session IDs are long and random enough, never re-used and invalidated immediately on use. Remember if keys aren't strong enough, given enough intercepted traffic you could determine future keys.

Cookies may be a more secure option if set to secure and http only

An attack vector here is your key checking API, as an attacker I'd be looking for ways to add my own keys to this so you need to check this is secure against injection attacks.

I also don't see how these IDs are tied to a specific user? Or are you also sending a user ID with your session ID.

Comment: Thx. Site 1 will store a reference to a user with the random ID. When the web service is used to validate the ID - other data will be sent back about which user it is. I'm not sure what you mean regarding cookies - how would that work? The IDs will be very long and very high entropy / random & single use yes. The key checking API will be a secured web service.

Comment: Instead of sending the session identifier  to the second site as a query parameter, you could add it to a cookie and attach that to your request. The benefit here is you can implement http only which tells the browser that only the server access it and use the secure flag to ensure it travels only over https. I would argue it is more secure than sending as part of the URL.

Comment: How about just posting it instead of using a querystring as suggested by @SilverlightFox ? Seems a bit simpler?

Comment: Yes - if you are able to do that, it's more secure than querystring and simpler than cookies

Answer (score 0):

You should use the fragment portion of the URL, instead of the search portion to transfer secrets. For good reasons mentioned by others, GET params are problematic, but the URL fragment (`#secret`) never even goes out over the wire, making it impossible to intercept from outside the computer.

This avoids CORS complications stemming from POSTing data across domains, and is actually more secure than POST because the secret stays local to the machine.

all you would have to do is link with a hash instead of a query:

`<a href="https://site2.com/auth?id=abc123 target=_blank>Log In</a>`
becomes
`<a href="https://site2.com/auth#abc123 target=_blank>Log In</a>`

you won't be able to reach the passed secret from the 2nd site's server, but it's available to the page's JS as `location.hash` or more exactly, `location.hash.slice(1)`.

Regarding the minor issue of human-visibility, you can remove the secret from the new page's URL bar immediately after grabbing the secret by calling `location.hash="";`, or to keep it out of the browser history: `history.replaceState("","","#");`.

If you're using HTTPS the whole way, POST would be about as secure and allow more content; hash (in my testing) is limited to about 20kb in older browsers. If you just need a key, hash is fast, *physically* secure, widely compatible, and easy to use.

EDIT:
along this notion, you can use another property, this one visibly hidden, called `window.name`. AFAIK, you can't use just HTML links for this, it takes a sliver of JS to arrange. You can use an iframe with just HTML, but you'll need JS to read the value anyway:

`<iframe name=secret123 href=https://site2.com/auth></iframe>`

inside the frame, `window.name` will be set to `secret123`. The special `name` property sticks around between page reloads and even last after navigating to 3rd party domains, so if that framed page ever navigates, you should first sanitize via `window.name="";`.

you can also easily use the *name* "trick" on a js-launched popup: `window.open("https://site2.com/auth", "secret123");`

Comment: Thanks - interesting input. The server does need the value in order to check it is real with the web service. Regarding CORS - is this really a huge problem when we are checking a very long large entropy random string with a web service in a separate secure back channel? What problem with my suggested solution does your input fix?

Comment: 1. not a "huge" issue, but not needing cors can greatly simplify integration, especially with load balancers or legacy infra. 2. Using the fragment instead of the query preclude problems from server logs and mitm (even w/o https). 3. replacing the location hides the secret from prying eyes, user's history, and the back button.

Comment: Thanks. It will be 100% https. The ID is single use so the back button isn't an issue?! We won't be using load balancers. We may be able to make site2 a subdomain of site1 - would that dodge the CORS issue? (either way, with a super long high entropy single use ID, do we even need CORS - where is the risk?)